# Android issue with edittextpreference and SharedPreferences

Tags: android, settings, preferences

I'm using a PreferenceScreen with fews edittextpreferences.

The problem is I'm using this same preference screen for severals items, and of course I don't want to show the same value for all items.(Imagine it's a settings screen for each news that I have on the app)

The problem is by default, when I change the value of one edittextpreference for one news, the value is changed for all my news when I tap on this edittextpreference.

To be more clear :

-> I go to the news1 settings -> I changed the value of "title settings"
-> I left the news 1, I go to news2 settings -> When I tape on the edittextpreference "title", I see by default the value entered in the news1 settings.

How to avoid it ? It's not possible to use a same preferences screens for different items ??